# How to read txt file that contains 2 documents written in a strange format?

Tags: java, hashtable, bufferedreader, information-retrieval, inverted-index

this is how my txt file looks like: [text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLVLb.png)

What I did to read the ".i" and ".m" from the 2 documents
but i didn't get any result, that hash table result = null.
is there any another way to read this txt file?

```
while(br.ready())
{
    String line = "" ; // br.readLine();
    while ( (line= br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //if line contains .I
        if (line.contains(".I"))
        {   //read the id and save it in id var
            String[] result = line.split("\\s");
            id = result [result.length - 1];
        }
        else if(line.contains(".M ")){
            String[] result = line.split("\\s");
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                if(!ht.containsKey(result[i]))
                {
                    ArrayList<tuple> temp = new ArrayList<tuple>();
                    int index = line.indexOf(result[i]);
                    tuple tmpTupl = new tuple(id+"", index+"");
                    temp.add(tmpTupl);
                    ht.put(result[i], temp);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The .M line doesn't have any words. The words are on the following line, which you ignore.

Comment: Also I think you will want `line.startsWith(".I ")`. And possibly even `line.equals(".M") || line.startsWith(".M ")` if you are not quite sure whether there may be a space after `.M`.

Comment: I have been staring at your code but have neither understood your data structure nor how the code was supposed to work. Maybe some more explanation would help. Surely there is a way of reading your text files.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yes , i think .. do u have any way to get the next line?